# How secure is to authorize a website to "trust your device"?

Tags: cookies, one-time-password, trust

A bank has a form of 2FA where, after you put in your username and password, they send a code via SMS  to your mobile phone and you have to put that too.

On the screen asking for the SMS code, there is an option to "trust this device", meaning that they won't ask for this SMS code (but still ask for username and password) on "my device".

1. How do the website knows that the one connecting is "my device" and so it doesn't have to send the OTP but let me pass through? I suspect it is done by cookies, but I don't know for sure.
2. Can someone "forge" a request to let it appear it comes from my device when in reality it doesn't?
3. How I am exposed in case someone steal my PC?

Answer (score 2):

The idea is, once you've proven you have some "a thing you have" second factor (a phone number), you can basically turn your PC into another "thing you have" second factor. Since it's usually vastly easier to steal somebody's phone number than their PC, this is probably fine.

1. It's done the same way any other long-term authentication token is handled. Probably a cookie but might be a bearer token from local storage (or similar). Obviously, until you authenticate the first time (including the SMS, in this case), that cookie won't be sent.
2. Unless the site is tremendously insecure, no. This should be as hard as just forging the session token that is given to your client after authentication (whether or not you specified "trust this device"). If the attacker can guess auth tokens for the bank, they wouldn't bother with the token that only bypasses one auth factor, they'd go straight for the one that just means they're logged in as you!
3. If somebody steals your PC and it's either running and logged in (not locked), or they're able to extract browser secrets off the HDD (they're either not encrypted or the password/key sucks), they will be able to bypass the second factor. They'll still need the first factor (password, a "thing you know" as opposed to "thing you have").